# QUnit test hangs

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

I'm new to qunit and JS testing. The code under test does an animation (slideDown) that must completed before I assert.  Seems simple, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
asyncTest('my test', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // assert something here
    start();
  }, 1000);
});
```

The callback is never called, and the test hangs.

I have tried various other ways too. For example:

```
test('my test', function() {
  expect(1);
  stop(1000);
  // assert something here
  start();
});
```

I can see that both `start` and `stop` are called, and the `test`  call finishes, but it still hangs.

In case it matters, here's my setup:

```
setup: function() {
  this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  this.server.respondWith([200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }, new_items()]);
  // invoke the actual system under test
  this.server.respond();
}
```

Comment: Does the first example work if you use only a simple assertion like `ok(true, "always fine");`? I.e. does `asyncTest()` work in general for you? Because if so, it must the your assertion code that breaks your test.

Comment: I might not have been quite clear, the callback passed into setTimeout never runs.

Comment: It is never called? No matter how simple the code in the assertion is?  What about [my jsFiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/9QDUX/)?

Comment: I feel pretty certain that whatever is inside the callback can have no effect on whether it is called. How could it?

Comment: That's true, unless there is a syntax error or something like that. My point is: your code looks good, I can't see an obvious mistake from that. Does `setTimeout()` work in general of you?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Sinon fake timer is on (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock). Call `this.clock.tick(1001)` after setting the timeout.